# Partial summation formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}+k\sqrt{k+1}}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am stuck in finding the partial summation formula for the following series. I need hint. $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}+k\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}+k\sqrt{k+1}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}({k+1}- k)}=?$$

Can you recognize the [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Answer (score 1):

Your work is almost done. Now $a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$. Now let $V_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$, then $a_k=V_k-V_{k+1}$. Now start putting the values of $k$ and add $a_k$. Finally you will get

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k=V_1-V_{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$ Now if $n$->$\infty$, then $S=1$ which is the final answer.

Hope this will be helpful !